# Recovering file of long running python process

Tags: python, file, pickle, recovery

I have a long running python process that periodically dumps a pickle using

```
    while True:
        do_something()
        pickle.dump(var, open('file','wb'))
```

I deleted 'file' assuming that it would be rewritten anyways but the file is gone forever. I thought python would create a new file-handler every time open() is called. Is there anyway to recover this file?  The process is still running and it would still write to 'file'.

It is a Ubuntu machine by the way

Comment: Are you sure the script isn't hung somewhere else? You're correct that a new file should be created. Also, how long has this script been running, and are you catching exceptions around this code? It is possible that if the script has been running for a long time, you are hitting the OS limit on open file descriptors since you aren't closing them properly.

Comment: I agree with above comment, on several layers, the script could be hung up somewhere else.  Does the script append to the file, I thought this would be 'w+', rather than just 'w'.  Also, you should use a context manager to open your file, in this case the ```with``` statement.

Comment: To check if multiple instances of the file are holding unnecessary descriptors due to improper closing, you can use "lsof | grep name_of_file".

Comment: I have a very similar setup that I am running on a web server and I have never had problems with "disappearing" files so far. I suspect the problemslies somewhere else? Maybe there script is hung in `do_something()` and never executes the `dump` call?

Comment: Are you sure there is no ~filename in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Linux, you should be able to do this:

1) find the PID of your Python script

```
ps -ef | grep myscript.py
```

2) look at the open file descriptors for your script

```
lsof -p <PID>
```

3) identify the file descriptor for the file you are interested in - it probably says "(deleted)" at the end of the line

4) make a copy of that file

```
cp /proc/<PID>/fd/<filedes> /some/other/path
```

Note that, if you have in fact run out of file descriptors, the most recent copy you can find in this manner may be quite old, depending on how often it's updated, and how long your script has been running. But, it's better than nothing. I would expect `open()` might have thrown an exception though, if you are truly out of file descriptors.

The other possibility that's been mentioned is that maybe you've never gotten to the `pickle.dump()` call, in which case the above won't help at all, because there won't be any files to recover...